# error: "No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'initWithTitle'

Tags: ios, objective-c, cocoa-touch

I am in the process of reading the O'Reilly book Learning Cocoa with Objective-C 3rd edition.

The O'Reilly website doesn't have a forum for this specific book, and searching for this error returns nothing.

On page 18, I keep getting the following error:

```
"No visible @interface for 'UIAlertView' declares the selector 'initWithTitle:message:deluge:cancelButtonTitle:otherButton'"
```

Here's my code:

```
//
//  ViewController.m
//  HelloCocoa
//
//  Created by ME on 1/14/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 ME. All rights reserved.
//

#import "ViewController.h"

@interface ViewController ()

@end

@implementation ViewController

- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.
}

- (void)didReceiveMemoryWarning
{
    [super didReceiveMemoryWarning];
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}

- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender
{
    UIAlertView* alert = [[UIAlertView alloc] initWithTitle:@"Hello!"
                                                    message:@"Hello, World!"
                                                   delegate:nil
                                          cancelButtonTitle:@"Close"
                                           otherButtonTitle:nil];
    [alert show];
    [_helloButton setTitle:@"I was Clicked!" forState:UIControlStateNormal];
}
@end



//
//  ViewController.h
//  HelloCocoa
//
//  Created by ME on 1/14/13.
//  Copyright (c) 2013 Andrew DiNatale. All rights reserved.
//

#import <UIKit/UIKit.h>

@interface ViewController : UIViewController
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *helloButton;
- (IBAction)showAlert:(id)sender;
@end
```

What's causing this error?

Comment: I don't know if it's a typo or not, but your selector reads `initWithTitle:message:deluge:cancelButtonTitle:otherButton`.  Deluge?

Comment: sorry , that was a typo, as you can see form the code i have it different. I tried to correct the title but i can't...

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The `otherButtonTitles` parameter is plural (as in `otherButtonTitle*s*`).

Comment: thanks, that fixed the error but now I have a second one. "No Vivible @interface for 'UIView' declares the selector 'setTitle:forState:'". Any suggestions?

Comment: Declare `helloButton` as a UIButton.  How old is this tutorial?

Comment: It was released in December 2012, I was not expecting to have this many errors so far... Sorry for my ignorance, I don't know how to declare it as a UIButton? Right now I just dragged the button into the .h file and added code from i book. I don't know anything yet.

Comment: No, change `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *helloButton;`, to `@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIButton *helloButton;`, and buy a better book!

Comment: Thanks, so far not so good... Do you recommend a good book or source?

Comment: I didn't learn from a book, so I can't really recommend anything good, experimentation and writing things for my own personal use were my teachers.  Try it sometime, it's not like you'll destroy your phone if you have one lousy error or misused API!

Comment: @Drewdin, I would like to second CodaFi's last comment. In the last couple of years I've made over 1000 Xcode projects, most with less than 50 lines of added code in order to learn objective-c/cocoa. Experimentation and the study of Apple's docs, as well as trying to answer other people's questions have taught me a lot.

Comment: Thanks guys, I appreciate it. I found the docs and I'm going to hammer away.

Answer (score 0):

UIAlertView is a UIKit (iOS) class.  Looks like you are trying to use it in a Cocoa project, instead of Cocoa Touch.

Comment: He'd get a lot more errors before that one in the .m if he was trying to compile this for OS X

Comment: I created an IOS single view application. All I added was a button to the display and the code above. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

I'm one of the authors on this book.

This question has already been correctly answered, but I just wanted to chime in - the answer from CodaFi is correct, the issue was that the method ends with "otherButtonTitles" (with an s), rather than "otherButtonTitle".

I just double-checked page 18 of the book, and it actually looks like the book had it correct!

If you have any other questions about the book, post 'em up here - I'll be floating around, looking for any questions that mention the book. Errata is always welcome!

Comment: I replicated the issue, it tells you to drag the button to the code page in the book. For some reason when i first did it it didn't populate properly. I deleted the code and moved it again and it worked fine. Thanks for the follow up